# Dynamically translate angular interpolation variables with i18n

Tags: angular, internationalization, translate

Hi i am trying to translate my user role in angular application. I have 4 roles: user, admin, superadmin and developer. And i want them translate dynamically as well. But no success with my implementation.

My html template.

```
<span i18n="@@{{user?.role | enumToString: UserRoleEnum}}">
    {{ user?.role | enumToString: UserRoleEnum}}
</span>
```

My translate units.

```
     <trans-unit id="developer" datatype="html">
        <source>developer</source>
        <target>vývojář</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="user" datatype="html">
        <source>user</source>
        <target>uživatel</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="admin" datatype="html">
        <source>admin</source>
        <target>admin</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="superadmin" datatype="html">
        <source>superadmin</source>
        <target>superadmin</target>
      </trans-unit>
```

Comment: The Angular native i18n support is only able to extract literal strings found in the templates, identified by a static ID, at compilation time. You can't do what you want with it.

Comment: well that is a bad news :(